# fastest way to bin elements into a 3D grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following 1D arrays

```
ix_array = [0, 2, 5]
iy_array = [0, 1, 2]
iz_array = [0, 0, 4]
w_array = [0.1, 2.1, 3.9]
```

and I want to use the first three arrays as indices to bin the w_array into a 3D grid. This can be done through something like

```
for i, (ix, iy, iz) in enumerate((ix_array, iy_array, iz_array)):
   A[ix][iy][iz] += w_array[i]
```

Is there something to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear how you want to distribute your w-data. Your sample code works only for list lengths of exactly three, so the generated outcome might not be what you actually want to achieve (or I do not understand your task at all). Guessing from your variable names, I assume it is something along these lines:

```
import numpy as np

ix_array = [0, 1, 1, 3]
iy_array = [0, 1, 1, 0]
iz_array = [0, 0, 2, 3]
w_array = [0.1, 2.1, 3.9, 7.1]

A = np.zeros((4, 5, 6))

A[tuple(zip([ix_array, iy_array, iz_array]))] += w_array

print(A)
```

Sample output:

```
[[[0.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]]

 [[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [2.1 0.  3.9 0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]]

 [[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]]

 [[0.  0.  0.  7.1 0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
  [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.ravel_multi_index` can be used to generate an array of flat indices and  `numpy.flat` to set the array `A` by these indices:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((6, 3, 5))
ix_array = [0, 2, 5]
iy_array = [0, 1, 2]
iz_array = [0, 0, 4]
w_array = [0.1, 2.1, 3.9]

arr = np.array([ix_array, iy_array, iz_array])
indices = np.ravel_multi_index(arr, A.shape)
A.flat[indices] += w_array
print(A)
```

output:

```
array([[[0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [2.1, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 3.9]]])
```